# Click listeners on a transparent layout with background items click-able

Tags: android, background, onclicklistener, transparent

I have created an activity which is transparent. The background is click-able, anything can be performed on mobile with activity opened. Now I want to set click listeners on the `textview` that is inside the transparent activity. I have searched but didn't find anything.

Here is the code to my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the `Java` code that i am using :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

[image: Sample]

I want the hello world to be click-able as well as other apps for example, Chrome, messaging, menu etc.

Comment: the textView is not getting clicked ryt ? whats the issue with this code ?

Comment: Textview is inside activity_main or inside any fragment

Comment: Sorry this was the old code. The textview is getting clicked but the background items are unaccessable. I am posting the updated code in a while

Comment: Updated it. Textview is inside main activity. There is no fragment yet.

Comment: wasnt hello world not clickable ?? in the below solution ?

Comment: It was clickable. But i couldnt access the chrome or other applications while the activity is running. I removed the get window part thats why i guess

Comment: if i make the window transparent, the listener is not working

Comment: try adding `tv.setFocusable(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with an activity. When  you use activity  it covers all of the screen and any touch done on screen will only accessible by that activity(If it transparent or not, this does not matter).

My suggestion is, try to use a widget instead of activity. It may fulfill your requirement. I suggest you to use any floating widget or permanently place that widget into center of the screen.

Below link may helpful for you.

[Chat Widget](http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html)

[Floating widget](http://www.androhub.com/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-messenger-chat-head/)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use activity for this purpose. you just call it form service class.

```
 windowManager2 = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_incoming, null);
        params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x=0;
        params.y=0;
        windowManager2.addView(view, params);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager2.updateViewLayout(view, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        txtNameIncoming = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.NameIncoming);

        txtIncomingnumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtIncomingnumber);
        txtIncomingnumber.setText("You have Incoming Call from " + PhoneStateReceiver.savedNumber);
        btnClose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         clearView(v.getContext());

        }
    });
```

xml will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#0090FF"
android:padding="10dp"
android:keepScreenOn="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NameIncoming"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Incoming Caller"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIncomingnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NameIncoming"
    android:text="Incoming Call Number"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Close" />
```

now modify it for yourself.